# Xamarin Forms Video Player (MediaManager Plugin)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, plugins, xamarin.forms

I am very new to Xamarin...

I am trying to create a youtube like app. I have no idea how to play video inside of my app. Ive tried to use the MediaManager plugin https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager but simply cannot figure it out.

If anyone could suggest a different plugin, or explain IN DETAIL how to use the MediaManager Plugin, that would be fantastic.

The docs on the plugin are atrocious, i cannot understand it at all.

Heres what I have so far: I am simply trying to play a video through a button click.

Xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App2.Video_Play_Page"
         Title="Video_Play_Page"
         BackgroundColor="#4B1388">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">

        <Label Text="video Player..." />

        <Button Clicked="PlayVideo" Text="Play me!"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Xaml.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

using Plugin.MediaManager;

namespace App2
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Video_Play_Page : ContentPage
{
    public Video_Play_Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PlayVideo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm8bQxnold0");
    }
}
}
```

NOTE: I dont know if I have installed everything correctly. If someone could please explain that, it would be great too.

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522846/7196681) help?

Answer (score 1):

You have almost everything there.

you need to instantiate the player like

In .xaml file

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="App2.Video_Play_Page"
    Title="Video_Play_Page"
    BackgroundColor="#4B1388"
    xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Plugin.MediaManager.Forms;assembly=Plugin.MediaManager.Forms">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">

            <Label Text="video Player..." />
            <forms:VideoView />
            <Button Clicked="PlayVideo" Text="Play me!"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

or in .xaml.cs file

```
new VideoView { };
```

but with your code i suggest the first option.

Then you will say to the plugin that you want to reproduce video and not audio.

```
private void PlayVideo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm8bQxnold0", MediaFileType.Video);
}
```

I'm not shure if the plugin reproduces videos with youtube url, if this doesn't work you should replace the url with an absolute url like

> https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/37af/240037cc-e74a-421a-9946-7ce4205d37af/DiAndIocForXamarinForms.mp4

[Here is a video to help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luDyX0kYzY4)

Answer (score 0):

You should put forms:VideoView in your Xaml file
Here is a sample to use it in Xamarin.Forms, check this 
https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/tree/develop/Samples/Forms

Comment: Link leads to 404

Answer (score 0):

### Xamarin Community Toolkit

I would recommend checking out the MediaElement in `Xamarin.Community.Toolkit`

It is a cross platform video player which is well documented at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement

You can generate the MediaElement in C# the same way you would any other control that can be created in Xamarin. It is very similar to the `Image` control in the way it works: allowing you to set aspect, whether or not to show the platform default video controls, etc...

In case you're quite new to Xamarin, heres the example from the link above:

```
<MediaElement Source="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4"
              ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
```

And the equivalent in C#:

```
MediaElement videoPlayer = new MediaElement
{

    Source = "https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4",
    ShowsPlaybackControls = false

};
```

Which can be added to any view in the same way you would add a `Label`, `Button` or any other control that inherits the `View` class.

A handy tutorial from Gerald Versluis (a member of the Xamarin team) can be found here which details all of the things you can do with the plugin (and also some common errors and how to fix them):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJAKkz17WDo

Answer (score 0):

If any still interested, this is an easy working sample for both Android and iOS which use Xamarin.CommunityToolkit's MediaElement

[xam-mediaelement-sample](https://github.com/AndreaGobs/xam-mediaelement-sample)